# ARM: fromelf - switches to get enum adresses in text output

Tags: c, struct, enums, arm, cortex-m

I use this command:

```
fromelf.exe -a project.axf > output.txt
```

to know my storage addresses in the Cortex-M3. All structs are listed there, with all flash and Ram addresses. How can I output the enums? I think they are all in the .axf - File? Axf = elf?!

Thanks.

Comment: enums don't have addresses - they're just numbers.

Comment: You might get a listing that includes enum names using the `-s` option.